# How to use multiple SSL certificates (JKS) while performing load runs with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I need to perform a load run with 100 User Load for an API with certificate-based authentication. I had SIX different certificates in JKS format. I would like to know how can we use all these six certificates while performing a load run. Can we have some configurations like we use CSV Data config for parameterizing data?

I tried by mentioning the path of all six certificates under Keystore properties of the System property file and when I run, Jmeter starts taking the SIX certificates in a sequel, but it didn't work

Is there any other configurations I can use?

Can you please help me in achieving this

Answer (score 1):

1. Put all your certificates into a [Java Keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore)
2. Point JMeter to use the keystore by manipulating `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` system properties
3. Add [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) element which will traverse the certificates in the keystore and use the different certificates for each thread (virtual user)

You can take a look at [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) article which contains step-by-step instructions on setting up keystore and JMeter